# Display issue TELERIK

Tags: asp.net

I have a small problem of display of my telerik objects on my page asp.net on the browser safari, the display is good on the other browser, chrome, firefox, IE

you have solutions ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is Safari for Windows, please note that it is discontinued and not supported by Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX.
If it is Safari on Mac, can you please share some screenshots of the problem?